# two way binding with safe navigation operator

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

What is the best way to use two-way-binding (syntax-sugar) in Angular 2 with the safe navigation operator. I've tried the following.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="x?.y?.z">
```

But this is not supported.

Is there a way to use sth. like this?

Answer (score 18):

You can split up- and downwards-binding like

```ts
<input [ngModel]="x?.y?.z" (ngModelChange)="x?.y?.z ? x.y.z = $event : null">
```

Comment: Just curious here, but doesn't the elvis operator essentially deprecate the "bananna-in-a-box" binding, since you're forced to split the bindings?

Comment: @rivanov not sure what you mean by that, but it needs to be split because you can't assign a value to and expression that uses the Elvis operator (`x?.y?.z = 'foo'` is invalid).

Comment: What I mean, seems to already be a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697

Comment: I understand that people want that, but if you check the 2nd-last comment, you'll see that it's not clear if this is technically possible.

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't support safe navigation operator in two-way bindings. Instead you can do this way:

```html
<!-- <input [(ngModel)]="x?.y"> -->
<input [(ngModel)]="x && x.y">
```

(tested with Angular 9)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input [ngModel]="x?.y?.z" (keyup)="changeMe($event.target.value)"> {{x?.y?.z}}

export class ParentCmp {
  x={y:{z:"a"}}
   changeMe(val)
    {
      console.log(val);
      this.x.y.z=val;
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBeSPqf4HUwLOeWSNfZJ?p=preview