# Set selected option if ngModel exists

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a select field as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myClient.address && myClient.address.state" name="state" (ngModelChange)="getCitiesByState($event)">
   <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let state of states" 
      [ngValue]="state">
       {{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```

However, as I'm reusing the same component, I would like my option to be set to a value if my `ngModel` has a value. For example, if `myClient.address` has `myClient.address = {"name":"Texas", "stateId":"2"}`, I want Texas to be the selected option.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two way binding with elvis-operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016407/two-way-binding-with-elvis-operator)

Comment: @echonax Does not help.

Comment: Seems you also need `compareFn` mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945001/binding-select-element-to-object-in-angular-2/35945293#35945293. For `ngModel` on `<select>` only object identity is compared by default. It doesn't check whether the properties of the objects are the same. If you want that, you need to implement `compareFn`

Comment: thin link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978450/angular-2-dropdown-options-default-value/41180705#41180705

Comment: Check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008374/how-to-set-the-initial-value-in-a-dropdown-in-angular2-for-a-different-object/43008690#43008690)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="myClient.address?.name" name="state" (ngModelChange)="getCitiesByState($event)">
   <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let state of states" 
      [ngValue]="state">
       {{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now if `myClient.address` has `myClient.address = {"name":"Texas", "stateId":"2"}`, I want Texas to be the selected option.

All the changes you need is `[ngModel]="myClient.address?.name"` add `?` , that defines optional behaviour , so if its provided then it will get selected and if not then it will work as there is nothing selected.

But here you have to provide atleast `myClient.address` with value or without value.