# setting initial value using ngModel for select dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have an array of `tranTypes` (transaction types) that are loaded into a dropdown.  After the user selects a value and navigates to another component upon returning the value is not selected in the dropdown.

From other readings, I've learned this is b/c the objects are not the same instance.  What do I do in this situation then?

```html
<select name="tranType"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="model.tranType"
    required>
   <option *ngFor="let tranType of tranTypes"
     [ngValue]="tranType">{{tranType.desc}}</option>
 </select>
```

**Solution**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.getTranTypes()
        .subscribe(tranTypes => {
            this.tranTypes = tranTypes;
            //set value of tranType if already set in the model
            if (this.myService.model.tranType != undefined) {
                this.myService.model.tranType = this.tranTypes.find(r => r.id == this.myService.model.tranType.id);
            }
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [4.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta6-2017-02-03) on, you can use a custom comparison function

```ts
<select [compareWith]="equals"
```

```ts
equals(o1: Country, o2: Country) {
   return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

for earlier versions you can look up the `tranType` in `tranTypes` by comparing content similar to above equals, and then assign the found instance to `model.tranType` to make it the selected one.

Answer (score 3):

You should have the value binded to the ngModel exactly same as that of your object inside array.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.tranType">
 <option *ngFor="let type of tranTypes" [ngValue]="type.id">{{type.Desc}}</option>
</select>
```

Best advisable to use id property as ngValue.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/7o1ETf0t6aJ216fEK96V?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

You must place the variable `model.tranType` inside a service that are loaded by a model that loads the two models you are navigating between. This way you will end up with a singleton service and the variable will be persisted while you are using your site. 
The problem in this approach is that if you refresh the page the service will be restarted and you will have the default option sleected again. To solve this, you must save the `model.tranType` variable state in localStorage, so even when closing the browser the option will remain the same.