# Angular2 Selected item on dropdown not displaying

Tags: angular, html-select, angular2-forms

I have been going through all posts here and still I cannot it working. I am trying to implement a dropdown in Angular2 which shows at first a selected value.

HTML.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="form-group">
     <select [(ngModel)]="selectedProjectType" class="form-control" required name="projectType">
     <option *ngFor="let projectType of projectTypes"> {{projectType.name}}</option>
      </select>
       <p *ngIf="selectedProjectType">{{selectedProjectType.projectType}}</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
selectedProjectType: ProjectType;

constructor(
private projectsService: ProjectsService){
this.project = new Project();
this.route.params
  .subscribe((params: Params) => { 
    this.projectsService.getProject(params['id']).then((project) => {
    this.project = project;
    this.selectedProjectType = project.projectType;
  });
 });}
```

The paragraph shows the correct selected project type while the select shows the first option. So I'm guessing I have assigned it right but I am having a problem in putting it as selected value for the select. I'm a beginner at Angular2 and I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is not a string, use `[ngValue]="..."` on `<option>`:

```
<option *ngFor="let projectType of projectTypes" [ngValue]="projectType">
  {{projectType.name}}
</option>
```

Comment: I am using ngValue since projectType is not a String and the dropdown shows blank..

Comment: If it's about the initial value (selected by code), you need to use `compareWith` like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008374/how-to-set-the-initial-value-in-a-dropdown-in-angular2-for-a-different-object/43008423#43008423

Comment: It worked ! Thank you a lot !!

Comment: Glad to hear :)