# Angular4: select [selected] not work for the first time

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

There is a code:

```
<select name="department" class="form-control select" [(ngModel)]="departments" formControlName="departmentControl">    
    <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department" [selected]="department.id == this.departmentid">
      {{ department.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

and function:

```
isSelected(department): boolean {
  debugger;
  return department.id == this.departmentid;
}
```

department - is a nested component for user-detail component. After I select a user-detail component for the first time, department not selected. But for second time everything works correctly. Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need of : `[selected]="department.id == this.departmentid"` as you are using `[(ngModel)]`

Change `[(ngModel)]="departments"` to `[(ngModel)]="departmentid"`

Change `[ngValue]="department"` to `[ngValue]="department.id"`

Finally it should look like this :

```
<select name="department" class="form-control select" [(ngModel)]="departmentid" formControlName="departmentControl">    
    <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department.id" >
        {{ department.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-default)**

Comment: @Galina, Okay great, I have created a demo also for that :) , Happy Coding

Comment: I was wondering why my code didn't work with [value], according to angular docs [value] only for strings and [ngValue] for objects (including numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Your `ngModel` is wrong you should have it as `departmentid` and the `ngValue` should be the id of the department as below

```
<select name="department" class="form-control select" [(ngModel)]="departmentid" formControlName="departmentControl">    
    <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department.id" [selected]="department.id == this.departmentid">
      {{ department.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Refer this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008374/setting-initial-value-using-ngmodel-for-select-dropdown/43008690#43008690)** for more information

Comment: @Galina Happy to help you :)