# Passing object in ngModel to a custom control Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I want to create custom control which contains other custom controls and use ngModel that connects all of them.
Like :

PersonSearchComponent :

- DeveloperSearchControl

  - Name - some string input
  - Surname
  - ProffesionSelect - custom control expecting ProffesionModel
- BuildingSearchControl

  - Some custom controls here
- CountryCustomControl - custom control expecting CountryModel

---

- PersonListComponent :
  -imported data about items from PersonSearchComponent by some service

---

- SomeOtherSearchComponent

  - DeveloperSearchControl - reusable

So for now I have working version, but I think i have made something bad (maybe I should use FormBuilder):

PersonSearch Template :

```
    <div>
            <developer-search-control [(ngModel)]="searchModel.developerSearchModel"></developer-search-control>
            <building-search-control [(ngModel)]="searchModel.buildingSearchModel"></building-search-control>
            <country-select [(ngModel)]="searchModel.countryModel"><country-select>
    </div>
```

ParentSearch component

```
...
export class PersonSearch {
  @Output() searchDataEmitter= new EventEmitter();//Exports data to above component which contains this, and listComponent
searchModel : PersonSearchModel : new PersonSearchModel();

    performSearch()
    {
        //gets data from service with searchModel and searchDataEmitter transpors it to above component
    }
}
```

Models :
PersonSearchModel :

```
developerSearchModel : DeveloperSearchModel = new DeveloperSearchModel();
buildingSearchModel: BuildingSearchModel = new BuildingSearchModel();
countryModel : CountryModel;
```

DeveloperSearchModel :

```
name : string
surname : string
proffesion : ProfessionModel
```

Template
developerSearchControl.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="value">//This is the problem
     <input [(ngModel)]="value.name"></input>
     <input [(ngModel)]="value.surname"></input>
     <profesion-select [(ngModel)]="value.ProffesionSelect">
</div>
```

developerSearchControl.component:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'developer-search-control',
  templateUrl: './developerSearchControl.component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DeveloperSearchControlComponent),
    multi: true,
  }],
})

export class DeveloperSearchControlComponent extends ElementBase<DeveloperSearchModel > {
  protected model: NgModel;

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<any>,
    @Optional() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<any>,
  ) {
    super(validators, asyncValidators);
  }
}
```

profesionSelect.component

```
    ...
@Component({
    selector: 'profesion-select',
    template: `
     <div>
        <label *ngIf="label">{{label}}</label>
        <dx-select-box 
            [dataSource]="data" 
            [(ngModel)]="value" 
            displayExpr="proffesionName" 
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
            [searchEnabled]="true"
            >
        </dx-select-box>
    </div>`,
        providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: ProfessionComponent,
        multi: true,
    }],
})

export class ProfessionComponent extends ElementBase<string> implements OnInit {
    private data: ProfessionModel[];
    private label: string = 'proffesion :';
    private placeholder: string = 'Select profession';
    @ViewChild(NgModel) model: NgModel;

    constructor(private proffesionService: ProfessionDataService,
        @Optional() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<any>,
        @Optional() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<any>,
    ) {
        super(validators, asyncValidators);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.professionService.getDevelopersProfessions().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = data;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

ElementBase is a generic ControlValueAccessor with validation from : http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/

So my problem is that when I create the template for children (developerSearch, buildingSearch) the value passed with ngModel is not initialized for them and i get :

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./DeveloperSearchControlComponent class DeveloperSearchControlComponent - inline template:2:33 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of null
Error: Error in ./DeveloperSearchControlComponent class DeveloperSearchControlComponent - inline template:2:33 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Because the value from ngModel is null at start. So I have to use *ngFor="value" in templates of child components which looks bad.
Is there any solution to initialize the object before template verification? or Im doing this very wrong?

Comment: did you try the elvis operator everywhere you use value ? something like `<input [(ngModel)]="value?.name"></input>`. At least, that will suppress the exception.

Comment: @mickdev Safe navigation operator cannot be used in `[(ngModel)]` ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 I never tried it but in my mind it was possible. I don't see why not ...

Comment: @mickdev It throws an exception as AJT_82 said. Already tried it :) but it still wouldn't look super nice in code.

Comment: @AJT_82 because you can't assign to something that contains `?.` You need to split it to `[ngModel]="foo?.bar" (ngModelChange)="foo && foo.bar = $event"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Great, thanks very much for the info! This is very useful to know! :)

Comment: I got it working like that in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LfutnLjn5clBt0z0rxfV?p=preview) but its not working in my a bit advanced solution, will try to create a pluker for it. But still is this the good way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a way to use two-way binding with safe-navigation operator:

```
<input [ngModel]="value?.name" (ngModelChange)="value?.name ? value.name = $event : null">
```

Props to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016472/5706293

Comment: That's the answer, i had to do some work with initialization of models also.