# textarea change is not detected with ngModelChange angular

Tags: angular

I am working with textarea in my component, but my ngModelChange seems not to be working.

```html
<textarea [ngModel]="something?.commentaire" (ngModelChange)="something.commentaire">{{something.commentaire}}
```

But when I change the commentaire of `something` in the text area, `{{something.commentaire}}` doesn't change.

Any idea how could I solve it?

This issue is different from that of [two way binding with elvis-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016407/two-way-binding-with-elvis-operator), because my question is not as regard the elvis operator and how to use it. Rather it is related to the way, the tag `textarea` handles the changes of event.

Comment: I think it could be useful for you to check out template syntax :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: @echonax I think this one is slightly different from the one you are referring to. The OP does not know that the `ngModelChange` is emitting the change through the `$event` variable.

Comment: @borislemke even if thats true, OP will have this knowledge by looking at the link :-)

Comment: I edited my question to explain in what it is different in comparison with the link @echonax provided

Comment: @edkeveked does the answer of Günter solve your question?

Comment: The answer of Günter doesn't answer my question. Because it doesn't explain the difference when handling the `<input type=text [ngModel]="something?.key" (ngModelChange)="something.key"> ` and when `textarea` is used instead.

Comment: @edkeveked handling `input` and `textarea` is not the issue here. The answer states that you need to assign `$event` to your model plus safe-checking null values with the elvis operator. Even if you just replace `x.y.z` from the answer with your field values, it again gives you the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `ngModelChange` binding attribute, you want to take the `$event` data and do something with it.

```
(ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)"
```

Above, the `$event` variable is the change that is emitted from the `textarea`.

*component.ts*

```
    doSomething($event) {

        // Do something with $event, you could for example,
        // convert it to an URL format
        // Imaginery function: "My name is Jeff" => "my-name-is-jeff"
        const uri = makeUri($event)

        // Now you have to set it to the variable you want it to 
        // bind to, so the model gets updated with the new value
        this.something.commentaire = uri
    }
```

If you don't need to do anything with the data and simply want to bind it to a variable, you can use the "banana in a box" syntax:

```
[(ngModel)]="something.commentaire"
```

Note that you cannot use the `elvis operator` to wait for data to be loaded, else it will break the model binding

```
[(ngModel)]="something?.commentaire" // Not working!
```

Under the hood, this syntax is practically replacing:

```
[ngModel]="something.commentaire" (ngModelChange)="something.commentaire = $event"
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use "banana in the box syntax" for `ngModel`:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="something.commentaire">{{something.commentaire}}
```

It is a shortcut that uses `ngModelChange` under the hood.

But it doesn't work with elvis operator, so you take advantage of `$event` in the `ngModelChange`:

```
<textarea [ngModel]="something?.commentaire" (ngModelChange)="something?.commentaire ? something.commentaire=$event:null">{{something.commentaire}}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the elvis operator with two-way binding AFAIR :/

Comment: It doesn't work. This syntax throws an error with the browser

Comment: @echonax, thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: @edkeveked, does the solution in the updated answer work?

Comment: I have already upvoted the solution of @borislemke. The easier way to achieve what I wanted is: `<textarea [ngModel]="something?.commentaire" (ngModelChange)="something.commentaire = $event">{{something.commentaire}} </textarea>`

Comment: @edkeveked, yeah, but you need elvis operator here `(ngModelChange)="something?.commentaire`, otherwise you'll get an error if `something` is undefined

Comment: Looks like `(ngModelChange)="something && something.commentaire = $event"` should also work

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, I think elvis operator was designed to simplify this pattern:  `a && a.b && a.b.c = a?.b?.c`

Comment: No, angular uses ternary operator for it

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.1/packages/compiler/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.ts#L404-L525

Comment: @yurzui, thanks :), I'll check it

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` for your need basis is absolutely correct. Only thing you need to do is call a function on `(ngModelChange)`. The event that is emitted by the angular (after model change) stored in the variable `$event` should be passed to that function. In your case event emitted is of type `string` which you can assign it to variable `something.commentaire`from the method `OnChange().`

```
<textarea [ngModel]="something?.commentaire" (ngModelChange)="OnChange($event)">{{something.commentaire}}

OnChange(event : string){
   this.something.commentaire = event;
}
```