# How to handle null variable while dealing with two way data binding in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template

I am using same component for edit as well as add new entries.

```
if(this.action='edit'){
    this._PersonnelService.getUsersById(this.selectedperid)
      .subscribe((userdata: Iuser) => { this.personnel = userdata[0]; this.personnel.perid = this.selectedperid;console.log(userdata[0]); }, (error) => {
        this.statusMessage = 'Problem with service. Please try again.'
        console.error(error);
      });
   }
    else{     this.personnel=null}

  }
```

Which means that if the `this.action` variable is `add` `this.personnel` will be set to null.

Now in HTML I have elements such as :

```
<input type="text"   class="form-control" name="PerFullName"  
[(ngModel)]="personnel.perfullname" id="fullname ">
```

I am getting truck load of errors in console. My textboxes aren't visible.
How do I fix this?

Comment: try by using undefined instead  null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two way binding with elvis-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016407/two-way-binding-with-elvis-operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the elvis operator ? in your html

```
<input type="text"   class="form-control" name="PerFullName"  
[ngModel]="personnel?.perfullname" (ngModelChange)="personnel?.perfullname personnel?.perfullname = $event : null" id="fullname ">
```

and the ?? in your javascript to set defaults incase of null

```
const j = null
y = j ?? 'Anonymous'
```

And this was answered previously here [two-way-binding-with-elvis-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016407/two-way-binding-with-elvis-operator/36016472).

Comment: As far as I know. Elvis (?) operator  does not work with two way binding

Comment: The elvis operator does work when you use [(ngModel)] as [ngModel]

Comment: but isnt [ngModel] used for one way binding?

Comment: it would be great if someone could explain `(ngModelChange)="personnel?.perfullname personnel?.perfullname = $event : null"` part