# Conditional expression bound with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

To [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389639/async-data-in-ngmodel) asking how to protect `[(ngModel)]="currentService.user.username"` when the variable is not yet defined, the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389922/1009922) was given:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="currentService.user && currentService.user.username">
```

At first, I thought that this could not work because the bound expression would not be a valid left-hand side in an assignment:

```
(this.currentService.user && this.currentService.user.username) = "Bob"; // Not valid
```

However, [Pardeep Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043867/pardeep-jain) provided a demo which showed that it does work: the variable `currentService.user.username` is bound to the input element once it is defined. [**This stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m81ght) is a forked version of his demo.

My question: is binding a conditional expression this way with `[(ngModel)]` supposed to work or does it work only "by accident" and may stop working in future versions of Angular?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, data bound expression is correct here in below line -

```
<input [(ngModel)]="currentService.user && currentService.user.username">
```

Because when you bind `ngModel` with such expression (`currentService.user && currentService.user.username`) , behind the scene it will
check for the first value and once it will be available then it will look for second value, if exist angular
will bind your value to that `ngModel` else bind with first one.

> (this.currentService.user && this.currentService.user.username) = "Bob"; // Not valid

This is not an valid syntax because here you are assigning value to some variable which you need to describe strongly
I mean either `this.currentService.user.username` or `this.currentService.user` not using `&&` seprator.

But yes if you write like this

```
this.bob = this.currentService.user && this.currentService.user.username // will be valid - here this.bob is some variable
```

Hope you get my point, if any confusion let me know.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused about the assignment part of two-way binding. I understand that `[ngModel]` would work with the conditional expression. But when the variable is updated with the input content, doesn't it work like an assignment? Apparently not. I don't know how the bound expression can be used like a variable that can be assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about Angular, this is about JS.

Look at this snippet :

```js
const variable = {
  user: {
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
};

console.log(variable);
console.log(variable.user);
console.log(variable.secondUser);
console.log(variable.user.name);
console.log(variable.secondUser.name);
```

As you can see, it tests if the variables are defined. When you try to access a property of a variable that is `undefined`, an error is being thrown.

What happens in your case, is that if the first condition is missed, the other conditions aren't tested.

Look at this snippet :

```js
const variable = {
  user: {
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
};

console.log(variable && variable.user && variable.user.name);
console.log(variable && variable.user && variable.user.surname);
console.log(variable && variable.secondUser && variable.secondUser.name);
```

This time, no errors are thrown. A [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930499/does-a-javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions-test-all-of-them) taught me that.

Second point, the `&&` operator **returns the value of the last expression if that expression is truthy or falsy**. Look at this snippet :

```js
const variable = {
  user: {
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
};

console.log(variable && variable.user && variable.user.name);
console.log(variable && variable.user && variable.user.surname);
console.log(variable && variable.user && !!variable.user.name);
console.log(variable && variable.user && !!variable.user.surname);
```

As you can see, if the last condition isn't a boolean, it will return the value of the condition.

By the way, in Angular, you can use the [Elvis operator](https://hackernoon.com/the-angry-angular-asyncpipe-the-evil-elvis-operator-89293e37e04d), which allows you to shorten the syntax (**but you can't use it in template driven forms**) :

```
<input *ngIf="currentService?.user?.username">
```

Comment: And and also, **[MDN explains that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)**

Comment: You're right I should have specified that. But since it's a specific case, I'll let it (for discovering purposes) and specify the ngModel case.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I often use the `&&` syntax with `[ngModel]` to return the second value (so I should not have been surprised with that). What I am confused with is that the expression becomes a reference to the second variable, allowing it to be updated with the input content. Not sure how that works.

Comment: It returns the variable, so you can instantiate a variable with it such as `let name = variable && variable.user && variable.user.name`. That's why it works with ngModel

Comment: Your example is for the "one-way binding" side (I understand that `[ngModel]="v && v.x"` works). But how does the other side of two-way binding work? In order to update the variable with the input value, it should do something like `v && v.x = input.value`. In normal code, the conditional expression returns the value of the second variable, not the variable itself. If it did, the invalid example in the question would be valid

Comment: I didn't go that deep into angular but I imagine that as I said, it returns a variable, si this equivalent to writing `variable.prop`, which works both ways.