# Issue when Reset template driven form / form's object typescript Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a component with a template driven form, which I have an object myObj that gets the values from the form's fields. The component looks something like:

```
export class a {
myObj:any;
..
..
initiateObj():void {
    this.myObj = {
       x:"",
       y:"",
       z:[],
       xy: []
   };
 }


..
..

reset():void {
   this.initiateObj();
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initiateObj();
  }
```

The view looks something like:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <input ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.x" #myInput="ngModel" />
  <input ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.y" #myInput1="ngModel" />

  <select ... [(ngModel)]="myObj.z">
  </select>
  ..
  .. 

  <button ....     (click)="submit()">
  <button ....     (click)="reset()">
</form>
```

when the component initiates the values in the console of myObj are:

x:" ",

y:" ",

z:[],

etc.

However, when I fill the form - even if I not fill the form, just click the reset button, the values of myObj in the console will be:

x: null,

y: null,

z:[null]

..

which causes an error when I need to use `myObj` again (when I need to use the form again).

When the component initiates for the first time, the values are Ok. But once I click the reset button, the values become null.

I tried to use in the view one way binding - `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`, and then when I click reset it's Ok, but then `myObj` will not get the values from the form - because it's one way binding. So I have to use two way bindings. But then when I click on reset the values of the object become null.

I asked here before and the answer I got was to Declare the class like this way:

```
export class initiateObj {
 x: '';
 y: '';
 z: [];
 xy: string;
 constructor(options: any = {}) {
   this.x = options.x || null;
   this.y = options.y || null;
   this.z = options.z || null;
   this.xy = options.xy || null;
}
}

  reset(): void {
     this.myObj = new initiateObj();
    }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.myObj = new initiateObj();
    }
```

But this solution also didn't work. I still get the same thing after I click reset.

Then I tried with `viewchild` to use the built in `reset` method - but it also didn't work. Still, once submit and reset again - the values become `null`

Then I realized in the console, that if I log to the console `myObj`, then after click reset and get the `null` values, it also gives another message attached to the object in the console:

"value below was evaluated just now"

So it seems that once I click reset I get the desire values, but then it changes immediately to the `null` values? Is it possible?

And if yes - then what is the way to resolve this?

I also tried with `viewchild` to access each form's field and give it "" or [] , but still I get `null`

How can I resolve it? (so I can submit and reset the form multiple times while stay in the component , and not need to reload again the page?)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz demo ? It will help us to get the answer.
And have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016472/5706293) ?

Answer (score 0):

`undefined || null` will return back null. If you do not pass any parameter value into your constructor, `options.x`, `options.y`, `options.z` and `options.xy` within the constructor will be `undefined`. Change your constructor to:

```
constructor(options: any = {}) {
   this.x = options.x || '';
   this.y = options.y || '';
   this.z = options.z || '';
   this.xy = options.xy || [];
}
```

then it should work

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried it. Yet didn't work. Then, the way I resolved it today, is by call this.initiateObj(); (in reset()) inside a callback of setTimeout. Then it works. I'm not sure however, if it the right way, and if there is more efficient way to do it? The question is why even I need the setTimeout? Is it a bug in angular forms? Is there other way than setTimeout to do it?